# How to store queries and their results in memcache using cache enabled for doctrine 2 (using zend framework 2 )?

Tags: php, caching, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I guess all is in the title , I've looked a lot for a solution but can't figure out how to do it ? Here is my configuration for `memcache` in `module.config.php` :

```
// Doctrine config
     'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ),
        )
            ),
            /***** enabling the memcache ****/
            'configuration' => array(
                'orm_default' => array(
                    'metadata_cache'    => 'mycache',
                    'query_cache'       => 'mycache',
                    'result_cache'      => 'mycache',

            )
            /**** end ****/
        )
    ),

    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
            'doctrine.cache.mycache' => function ($sm) {
                 $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache();
                 $memcache = new \Memcache();
                 $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
                 $cache->setMemcache($memcache);
                 return $cache;
         },
        ),
    ),
```

i'm using zend framework 2 and doctrine 2 .
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is configured correctly you don't need to configure anything else for `Query Cache` and `Metadata Cache` to work, however, to enable `Result Cache` you will have to call `useResultCache` explicitly on each query.

Example:

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery('select u from \Entities\User u');
$query->useResultCache(true);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , it's working for the result cache , but what for the query cache ? i mean i've enabled the memcache for storing the transformation of DQL Query to SQL query ? also how about if i have some complicated query for example ,  i don't wanna get object but sum or avg , how can i store it and get it after ?

Comment: yes, that is the purpose of `Query Cache` it parses the `DQL` to `SQL` only once. Answering your second question: `Result Cache` stores already hydrated object, so, it will store whatever you are expecting to retrieve from the db